# WPF:prevent raising "StaticResource not be resolved" Exception?

Tags: wpf, staticresource

As we konw,if the key hadn't been found,it would raise an exception.
But, is there a way to **prevent** this and just set the control's visibility to be **Hidden**?Or give it a **FallbackValue** just like Binding?

A simple example:
`<TextBlock Text="{StaticResource  myKey}"/>`
Now "myKey" doesn't be defined,it'll raise an exception by default.But I wish I can set TextBlock's Visiblity to be hidden:
`<TextBlock Text="nothing here" Visibilty="Hidden">`
or:
`<TextBlock Text="nothing here" FallbackValue="default value">`(Notice:"FallbackValue" does'nt really exsit)
then the application could continue.Nothing wrong,cheers :)

Comment: Throw in a little more specifics and people will probably receive your question a little more openly.

Comment: @plast1K Sorry for that,it's just an simple idea,a little strange maybe :)

Comment: im having trouble understanding why you would want to bind your text propety to a static resource if it is going to be dynamic . maybe you should use databinding instead? for the visibility part, you can use a datatrigger that hides the textbox if the text is null and another datatrigger that hides it when the text is empty

Comment: @failedprogramming Thank you for you suggestion :) Just like I said,it's a strange idea :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Simple implementation:
We can inherit [StaticResourceExtension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.staticresourceextension.aspx)(Yeah,it's not sealed :)),then override [ProvideValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.staticresourceextension.providevalue.aspx) method,return a default value.
Solved:)

Answer (score 0):

So far I could understand your question, you may put your code into a try clause, and catch exception.. It will atleast allow you to perform operation with the control. (Remember you may use finally clause for forceful execution) ..

If my assumption is wrong, I apologize in advance and request to be more specific :) good luck

Comment: You, unfortunately, won't be able to put a `try {} catch {}` in the XAML.